# Qt QScript Crypto

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

I am developing a Qt application and I am using QScript to write javascript "extensions" for my program.

I need to securely store a password, so I want to use SHA3-512 or PBKDF2 or HMAC
I found a javascript library that implements the above.

[link to library](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)

I am using this simple example of QScript.

[link to QScript example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/script-helloscript-main-cpp.html)

My question is, how can use that library, more specifically, how can I make that library available to my javascripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to evaluate the additional script files you want to use before you evaluate your own custom code. For the library you picked that might be some work since there are A LOT of files, but this will hopefully get you started (assumes the sha1.js from that library is in the directory from where you execute the program):

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtScript>

void loadScriptFile(QScriptEngine &engine, const QString &fileName) {
    QFile scriptFile(fileName);
    scriptFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QTextStream stream(&scriptFile);
    QString contents = stream.readAll();
    scriptFile.close();

    QScriptValue value = engine.evaluate(contents, fileName);
    if (value.isError()) {
        qCritical() << "Unable to load " << fileName;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QScriptEngine engine;
    loadScriptFile(engine, QLatin1String("./sha1.js"));

    QScriptValue output = engine.evaluate("CryptoJS.SHA1(\"Testing 1 2 3\");");
    qDebug() << output.toString();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Btw, if you're using Qt 5.0 or higher, consider using QJSEngine instead of QScriptEngine: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qjsengine.html. It's faster and more actively maintained. The API is nearly identical so porting your code over should be easy.

Comment: Aha! Thank you, I didn't realize there was a QJSEngine Class. If I need just SHA1.js, can't I just add sha1.js to my project, or would I still need to add all the files from that library?

Comment: That library seems to be clever enough that each file is stand alone, so you can just add the one file. That example that I showed actually runs and works with just the 1 file added.